# Play! Framework 2.5 form encoding

Tags: encoding, playframework, upgrade, form-submit

After upgrading from Play! 2.4 to Play! **2.5** there seems to be a problem with **form-enconding**. German umlauts for example really get messed up. For example the german word "Bär" becomes "BÃ¤r".
I already changed the way I access form data from

```
Form.form(Form.class).bindFromRequest();
```

to the injected way, as described in the migration guide:

```
formFactory.form(Form.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Is there a was to fix the character encoding in **Play 2.5**?

Comment: I have same problem for Persian in play 2.5, "تهران" converts to  "ØªÙØ±Ø§Ù"

Comment: I report this problem in Play project in Github: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5919

Comment: This problem has been fixed in Play 2.5.1. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form try adding the accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"

```
<form  accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" action="whatever" method="post">
```

tested it for the word `Bär` and it works fine

**EDIT:**

For the arabic script the characters are stored as ISO-8859-1 encoded as well. An image to show that at the end all goes well.

[image]

Comment: with    ''@helper.form(action = routes.UserController.register(), 'class -> "form-horizontal", Symbol("accept-charset") ->"ISO-8859-1") '' 
problem still exists for Persian charachters

Comment: yes mohsen it does not display the arabic script however saves the correct encoding so when you copy the jumbled text to an editor, it can be successfully converted to your arabic script. so you data is saved in the correct encoding and without the charset the exact words are lost

Comment: the word "تهران" is stored as iso-8859-1 encoding "&#1578;&#1607;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606;", this is how it should be. if you google these characters, google converts them to the correct encoding

Comment: You guys rock! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @mohsinkhan this problem caused by play framework body parser, characters displayed in server side encoded

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in play 2.5 , see github issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5920

I resolve this with a custom body parser:

```
   package com.kashi.ssff.services;

import akka.util.ByteString;
import play.api.http.HttpConfiguration;
import play.core.parsers.FormUrlEncodedParser;
import play.http.HttpErrorHandler;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.streams.Accumulator;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;
import play.mvc.BodyParsers;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by mohsen on 3/21/16.
 */
public class FormBodyParser extends BodyParser.BufferingBodyParser<Map<String, String[]>> {
    private final HttpErrorHandler errorHandler;

    public FormBodyParser(long maxLength, HttpErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(maxLength, errorHandler, "Error parsing form");
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    @Inject
    public FormBodyParser(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration, HttpErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(httpConfiguration, errorHandler, "Error parsing form");
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator<ByteString, F.Either<Result, Map<String, String[]>>> apply(Http.RequestHeader request) {
        return BodyParsers.validateContentType(errorHandler, request, "Expected application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                ct -> ct.equalsIgnoreCase("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), super::apply);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String[]> parse(Http.RequestHeader request, ByteString bytes) throws Exception {
        String charset = request.charset().orElse("UTF-8");
        return FormUrlEncodedParser.parseAsJavaArrayValues(bytes.decodeString(charset), charset);
    }
}
```

and annotate controller with this body parser:

```
    @BodyParser.Of(FormBodyParser.class)
    public Result register() {
.
.
.
```

With special thanks @GregMethvin

Comment: yes @Mohsen, indeed play is not parsing the body correctly